# Does the protagonist's age matter in a 3rd person shooter?

Tags: game-design, character

There have been very young characters in modern games that wield weapons including firearms before. Two good examples include [Ellie](http://static2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130620173236/thelastofus/images/f/f3/50950.jpg) from The Last of Us, and [Clementine](http://cdn2.gamefront.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/clementine.jpg) from The Walking Dead. Whilst I don't support the idea of having gun wielding children as characters, I do understand the context of use in the above two examples and the points being made.

I am designing the concepts of a 3rd person action game. The protagonist is a modern male adolescent (about 13 years old) and their age is important because the game's design is centred around the idea of growth and having the protagonist learn and achieve milestones through the game's progression. Being an action game there is combat and weapons including firearms. What I would like to know is, is there particular considerations I need to take with the issue of having firearms and a very young protagonist? At the moment the gameplay progression has the protagonist starting of as completely unarmed, having to initially rely solely on hand to hand combat and other stealth and platformer based skills to progress and learn new abilities. I would like to make more weapons and eventually firearms available to the protagonist, but have their use be completely up to the player and not a necessity for game progression. Most importantly I would like to make sure that the finished game does not come across as promoting the underage use of guns.

So is the protagonist age an important consideration in this type of game genre, or not? For example would I need to make sure I include a tutorial scene where the protagonist is taught how to fire a gun by an adult?

Comment: Is this an ethics question, a legal question, a storyline question or a gameplay question? In any of the cases, it's likely completely opinion-based. Do *you* think it's OK?

Comment: It is a combination of ethics and legal, which would of coarse affect the gameplay depending on which way it went (yes/no). Personally I think it's ok if the player is given the choice, but I can't speak for everyone and so I wanted to see how people with more industry experience would approach this.

Comment: This is very subtle. Of course murder is not ok but it is also widely accepted that murder in games is ok. Most countries have rules against underage sex games but not underage violence. See this game: https://www.google.co.il/search?q=videogame+bully&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=6QTtUt3JKK2P4gTi7YHABQ&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=1536&bih=762

Comment: The [No Russian mission in MW2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controversies_surrounding_Call_of_Duty:_Modern_Warfare_2) had some high-profile controversy for having the player fire into a crowd of realistically reacting civilians. The game was of course rated 18+ and in some countries the mission was censored or removed altogether.

Comment: Yes I definitely have done my fair share of research about game controversies, including the one from MW2 you mention Anko. I find it surprising that the two examples I mentioned above (The Last of Us and The Walking Dead) were not deemed that controversial, based on my research at least, even though they have a 8 year old and 13 year girl respectively firing guns at zombies. This is one of the reasons why I think in my case it wouldn't be such a problem.

Comment: Zombies ALWAYS make things better as far as pleasing the censors goes. In Carmageddon 2 they just swapped the humans with zombies and suddenly the game was accepted in Germany. If the kid is fighting robots, weird aliens or anything like that it's fine. If you are fighting living human beings prepare for problems.

Comment: Yes I remember the Carmagedon controversy, it's quite hilarious how the zombies made all the difference. I think as you suggested the character would need to at least look like an adult or close to it.  Or the age could be "unknown" like in the Dead or Alive series, where the underage female characters had their ages wiped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get serious legal advice contact a lawyer.
Games exist where under-aged characters perform violent acts:
[Bully](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=videogame%20bully&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=6QTtUt3JKK2P4gTi7YHABQ&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=1536&bih=762)

I can't say if it's ethical (your game idea). I think it isn't because it gives the impression that kids are allowed to use firearms against other kids. We all know that only adults are allowed to play dress-up, wear uniform and commit mass murder of complete strangers and only if it's sanctioned by their government.

So I think your game idea is possibly not legal for both good reasons and hypocritical reasons.

On second thought, Kickass is all about kids killing others and Battle Royal is kids killing kids so maybe.. You could pull it off in game land somehow but I doubt any publisher will agree to help with it.

Comment: I am pretty sure they wouldn't allow you to distribute a game shot at anything other than something that was already dead (robots, zombies, spirits and such).

Comment: True Bully does have violence but as far as I'm aware it doesn't have any guns in the game. In my particular concept it would be more of a case of a "kid" in an adults world rather that kids shooting other kids.

I think another good example is Assassin's Creed 2, where the protagonist is a 16 year old adolescent and yet goes on a mass murder crusade after the death of his parents, using weapons including primitive firearms. I think that is closer to the concept I am going for: a young person having to grow up fast and become a "warrior" or "hero" because of the situation the antagonist put...

Comment: hmm.. He doesn't appear childlike though, does he now? If your 13 yo kid looks like a 31 yo badass, I think you're fine. Hell if you can make it maybe you"ll thrive on negative publicity.

Comment: Ok so I guess the characters appearance is important. What if the player was able to create their own character similar to the Saints Row series. When the game starts the protagonist's character would be introduced but after the first mission the player would be able to change their appearance, age etc. Your thoughts on this?

Comment: In theory if you hide it like that it might not be a problem at all. For instance in City of Heroes there was an option to design your character to look (a lot) like child. I did not see many who did that but the option was there all along. So I suppose if you let people choose to make a childlike character it may put off some publishers but if it's obfuscated by many other options, they may not notice. Again, they might get upset simply by the age's numerical value.

Comment: In terms of appearance the only "childlike" feature I've considered implementing is just a simple height/size adjustment to make the character a little shorter to start of with. They won't be wearing a school uniform or anything like that. I think AC2 is a good example for me to follow as it deals with a very similar concept, even though my protagonist will be a few years younger than Ezio. Btw, I tried to vote up your answer but I don't seam to have the privileges for that yet.